# Problem with NLOG WhenRepeatedFilter and multiple targets

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm adding Sentry to one of my target in NLOG (4.6.4). Because we sometimes have multiple error trigger a great number of times i created a WhenRepeatedFilter to stop the repeated errors and only log 1 of them with a counter in it. This Filter is already working on my mailtarget.

When i add this filter also the my Sentry Target. The mailtarget still works but the Sentry target stops working. Do i add the wrong way?

When i try changing the order of the targets my mailtarget stops working and Sentry is working.

```
LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();

var WhenFilter = new WhenRepeatedFilter();
WhenFilter.Layout = "${message}";
WhenFilter.TimeoutSeconds = 600;
WhenFilter.Action = FilterResult.Ignore;
WhenFilter.IncludeFirst = false;
WhenFilter.FilterCountPropertyName = "filteredCount";
WhenFilter.FilterCountMessageAppendFormat = "\n\nIgnored: {0}";

//File log instellen
FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();

fileTarget.FileName = Path.Combine(LogPath, "automate.log");
fileTarget.ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(LogPath, "automate.{#####}.log");
fileTarget.ArchiveAboveSize = 512000; // 500kb
fileTarget.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Sequence;
fileTarget.MaxArchiveFiles = 10;
fileTarget.ConcurrentWrites = true;
fileTarget.KeepFileOpen = false;

fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} | ${level} | ${callsite} | ${event-properties:item=DebId} | ${event-properties:item=Gebruiker} | ${message}";


var BufferTarget = new BufferingTargetWrapper()
{
    BufferSize = 100,
    SlidingTimeout = false,
    FlushTimeout = 5000,
    Name = "BufferTarget",
    OverflowAction = BufferingTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Flush,
    WrappedTarget = fileTarget
};
config.AddTarget("file", BufferTarget);

LoggingRule ruleFile = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, BufferTarget);
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleFile);

//Mail log instellen

MailTarget mailTarget = new MailTarget();
config.AddTarget("mail", mailTarget);

mailTarget.Name = "mail";
[....]
mailTarget.AddNewLines = true;
mailTarget.Layout = "${longdate} | ${windows-identity} | ${event-properties:item=Versie} | ${level} | ${callsite} ${newline} ${event-properties:item=DebId} | ${event-properties:item=Bedrijf} | ${event-properties:item=Gebruiker} | Dubbele overgeslagen:${event-context:item=filteredCount}}${newline}${event-properties:item=Ips}${newline} ${message}${newline}${newline}Stacktrace: ${stacktrace}${newline}Callsite: ${callsite}${newline}Exception: ${exception}";
mailTarget.Subject = "NLog ${level} bij ${event-context:item=Bedrijf} (${event-context:item=DebId})";
if (GlobInfo.IsServer)
    mailTarget.Subject = "NLog Server ${level} bij ${event-context:item=Bedrijf} (${event-context:item=DebId})";

LoggingRule ruleMail = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, new LimitingTargetWrapper(mailTarget, 100, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
ruleMail.Filters.Add(WhenFilter);
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleMail);

//Sentry
var SentryTarget = new SentryTarget();
SentryTarget.Name = "Sentry";
[....]
SentryTarget.MinimumEventLevel = LogLevel.Error.ToString();
SentryTarget.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogLevel.Debug.ToString();
SentryTarget.Options.InitializeSdk = true;
SentryTarget.Options.ShutdownTimeoutSeconds = 5;
SentryTarget.Options.AddTag("App", GlobInfo.IsServer ? "Server" : "Client");
SentryTarget.Options.AttachStacktrace = true;
SentryTarget.Options.Release = GlobInfo.UpdBuildnr.ToString();
SentryTarget.Options.Environment = GlobInfo.UpdVersie;
SentryTarget.IncludeCallSite = true;
SentryTarget.IncludeCallSiteStackTrace = true;
SentryTarget.Layout = "${message}";
SentryTarget.Options.BeforeSend = BeforeSend;

LoggingRule ruleSen = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Error, new LimitingTargetWrapper(SentryTarget, 100, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
ruleSen.Filters.Add(WhenFilter);
config.LoggingRules.Add(ruleSen);
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting. When NLog stops working there is for sure an error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract this as method:

```
var WhenFilter = new WhenRepeatedFilter();
WhenFilter.Layout = "${message}";
WhenFilter.TimeoutSeconds = 600;
WhenFilter.Action = FilterResult.Ignore;
WhenFilter.IncludeFirst = false;
WhenFilter.FilterCountPropertyName = "filteredCount";
WhenFilter.FilterCountMessageAppendFormat = "\n\nIgnored: {0}";
return WhenFilter;
```

Instead of reusing the same `WhenFilter` for both logging-rules.

Alternative add both targets to the same logging-rule.

Comment: Thanks, That was my mistake i'm reusing the filter.
Used you're solution and this works perfect.